# How to queuing schedule job in Quartz

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, task-queue, job-scheduling

I have three job such as cleanJob, exportJob and reportJob which scheduled by quartz. And my system allow user to rescheduler job on UI operation, so those jobs may be scheduled at same time such as 3:00 AM.

Are there any way to do queuing job function in quartz? When those jobs scheduled at same time it would be executed one by one, but not concurrently.

Thanks.